# Jquery color event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple selection and the user can select one thing and it will copy the text into an input above.

I would like that the text in the multiple selection that will be copied become red if the button is clicked so did you understand?

I don't know how to do condition in Jquery, here is what I have done :

```
var choose = function(bouton){
    var lesoptions = $('#droite').find(":selected");
    $('#numLot').val(lesoptions[0].text);
    $("#ok").click(function(){
        $("#droite").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
    })
};
```

`droite` is an id, `ok` is an id and `numlot` as well the function is taking the select field and copy it into an input and i would like that the select field become `yellow` but it's not working. It enters into the function but doesn't do what i ask

And if possibly i want it to became in read-only how can i do this ? but i don't how to do this if you could help .
Thanks

Comment: try removing the curly braces on your `.css()`

Comment: please share jsfiddle link of your problem

Comment: @Yaje It's valid because that is another syntax of applying more than one style rules to an element!

Comment: Did you actually call the `choose` function anywhere, and you're setting the color of the select, not the selected option ?

Comment: Seems to be working just as expected -> http://jsfiddle.net/Zcx65/

Comment: but now not only the selected gets yellow. BUt that'S what you want to have in the end right?

Comment: yes all the content became yellow it's not what i wanted i wanted only the option

Comment: You can't change the style of a single option, option tags are not styleable in most browsers.

Comment: can i put the value instead of the value in jquery for exemple instead of #droite i put the value of the option

Comment: When it's closed you can color the whole select, and when it opens you can color the whole select white and only the selected yellow. This way the user thinks, that you colored just the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I took your example and just revamped it a bit. Here's one solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/H4PNe/

**Jquery**

```
$('#ok').click(function(){
    $('#droite').val($('select').val());
    $('select option:selected')
        .siblings('.selected')
        .removeClass('selected')
        .end()
        .addClass('selected');
});
```

**Class:**

```
.selected {

    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**Html**

```
<input id="droite" type="text">
<select>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<button id="ok">OK</button>
```